# How to use an external service as a source for Grails app configuration?

Tags: grails, configuration, groovy

[Section 3.4](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#configExternalized) of Grails documentation says that Grails app can be configured from an external source:

```
grails.config.locations = [
    "classpath:${appName}-config.properties",
    "classpath:${appName}-config.groovy",
    "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.properties",
    "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.groovy" ]
```

Also, it is possible to load config by specifying a class that is a config script:

```
grails.config.locations = [com.my.app.MyConfig]
```

My questions are:

1. Could you please give an example of how MyConfig class implementation could look like? It is not quite clear from the documentation.
2. If I want to use some external JSON REST service as a source for my config data, how can this be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for second question: you can do that in BootStrap.groovy init closure, because basically, it allows you to execute any code:

```
// Inject grails app
def grailsApplication

def init = { servletContext ->
    def externalValue = getItUsingRest(someUrl)
    grailsApplication.config.my.custom.var = externalValue
}
```

Depending on version of grails you are using, you might need to use

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolde.config
```

to get to config instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your application configuration can actually be a Groovy script. So any class which looks like your Config.groovy can act as a configuration class. In our projects we tend to keep the configuration outside the grails application so that the application can be configured without recompiling everything.

Maybe [this post of mine](http://www.pasopas.nl/2012/loading-grails-configuration-files-update/) will give you a hint on how to use and load external configuration files.